# json data with multiple arrays displaying in a table

Tags: php, json

i have a json data like so

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "apple": [
                {
                    "id": 127,
                    "type": 1,
                    "color": green,                   
                    "stage": 1,                    
                    "status": 1                   
                },
                {
                    "id": 128,
                    "type": 2,
                    "color": red,                   
                    "stage": 1,                    
                    "status": 1  
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "oranges": [
                {
                    "id":133
                   "type": 3,
                    "color": rainbow,                   
                    "stage": 1,                    
                    "status": 1   
                },
                {
                   "id":134
                   "type": 3,
                    "color": black,                   
                    "stage": 1,                    
                    "status": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "berry": [
                {
                    "id":4
                   "type": 2,
                    "color": white,                   
                    "stage": 1,                    
                    "status": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "watermelon": [
                {
                    "id":5
                   "type": 2,
                    "color": red and blue,                   
                    "stage": 1,                    
                    "status": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bleh": "Succesfully queried database"
}
```

i would like to create a table in php that goes somthing like this

```
Fruit |  Type | color
apple    1     green
apple    2     red
oranges  3     rainbow
oranges  3     black
```

so basically what i want is when ever a object like apple has more then one array inside it the table to display `apple` and the corresponding data to it.
this is what i have so far

```
 $output = json_decode(JsonData);
     $result =$output['data'][0]['apple'];

<table>
    <thead> 
            <tr>                
                <th>Fruits</th> 
                <th>Type</th> 
                <th>color</th>                 
            </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
        <?php if(!isset($result)){ ?>
        <tr> 
            <td>Empty</td> 
            <td>Empty</td> 
            <td>Empty</td> 
            <td>Empty</td>       
        </tr> 
        <?php else{
            foreach($result as $apples){ ?>              
            <tr> 
                <td></td> 
                <td><?php echo "$apples["type"]";?></td> 
                <td><?php echo "$apples["color"]";?></td>                    
            </tr> 
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Comment: whats this `<?php echo "apples["type"]";?>`

Answer (score 1):

Well just at a glance this is completely wrong syntax

```
<?php echo "apples["type"]";?>
```

Probably you need something like this

```
<?php echo $apples["type"];?>
```

What you had will probably give you a syntax error because PHP will see it like this

```
<?php echo "apples["   type   "]";    ?>
```

Where `"apples["` is a complete string, `type` is an undefined constant that is unexpected in the location it's in, and then an extra string `"]";`

you can test it in this sandbox

https://3v4l.org/nR8vF

Which gives us this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'type' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /in/nR8vF on line 5
```

**UPDATE**

Well there are a few other obvious problems, just with this

```
$output = json_decode(JsonData);
$result = $output['data'][0]['apple'];
```

I assume `JsonData` is just a placeholder or are you missing the `$` on that too?

Then as you don't have the second argument set to true, then `data` will be object style.  Personally I would do

```
 $output = json_decode(JsonData, true);
```

And just use it as an array.

Others have covered the double "foreach"  deal (for looping on fruit), so I won't re-hash that, I would have covered it but it was "Dinner" time and my wife gets a bit "Irritated" when I mess with code instead of coming up from the office (I have an office in the basement).

Comment: its the same thing it doesn't matter if its inside a `"` its just easier to concatenate stuffs like that

Comment: It's not the same because `"apples` is a string and `$apples` is a variable.  You may have an argument if you had, had `"$apples['type']"` but that's not what you have.  Even then I prefer to wrap it in `{}` such as `"{$apples['type']}"` as it makes it much more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true); 
foreach($arr['data'] as $fruit => $types){
 foreach($types as $info){
 echo $fruit;
 echo $info['type']; 
 echo $info['color'];
}
}
```

This is how you can get your JSON data into PHP. I trust you can create an HTML table or something to display this information.

Comment: hello
when i `echo $fruit` i get a output as `0123`

Comment: also `$info['types'];` says undefended index

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show all fruits then you will need something along the lines of:

```
$result =$output['data'];
```

Then update your foreach loop

```
foreach($result as $key=>$fruit){ 
    foreach($fruit as $k=>$dets){?>              
        <tr> 
            <td></td> 
            <td><?php echo $dets["type"];?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $dets["color"];?></td>                    
        </tr> 
<?php } 
} ?>
```

That's also not valid json

Comment: why do u say its not valid?